# Load Assembly compiled with newer .Net Framework than executing assembly

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection, .net-framework-version, .net-4.8

I have an application compiled with `.Net Framework 4.0` and I want to load a WPF UserControl inside it.
The user control is a dll compiled for `.NetFramework 4.8`.

I have been doing some tests with Console Application and I have loaded from .NetFramework 4.0 a dll using reflection. The dll is compiled with .NetFramework 4.8 and using for example the RSA constructor introduced in .NetFramework 4.7

Console App targeting `.NetFramework 4.0`

```
static void Main()
{
    var path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "DependencyDll.dll");
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(path);
    var type = assembly.GetType("Crypto");
    var typeInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    var method = type.GetMethod("Encrypt");
    var text = (string) method.Invoke(typeInstance, new object[]{"Hellooooo"});
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Class library Dll targeting `.NetFramework 4.8`

```
public class Crypto
{
    public string Encrypt(string text)
    {
        using(var rsa = RSA.Create(2048))
        {
            var bytes = rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text), RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA512);
            var decrypt = rsa.Decrypt(bytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA512);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypt);
        }
    }
}
```

In this example it seems that everything works well with no problem at runtime.
Is this permited or maybe I will have some problem? I thougth that this will fail due the executing or calling assembly was compiled in `.Net Framework 4.0`.

Comment: Can't you update your application to .NET Framework 4.8? Support for 4.0 was ended Jan 12, 2016 so it is not recommended to keep using it as there haven't been any updates or security fixes since then. More info on the lifecycles can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework

Comment: @GuyVdN The application has to be supported in older systems like Windows XP and the application also is not developed by me. I develop only the UserControl dll. The application runs on not connected environment so the risk of security it's limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this permited or maybe I will have some problem?

Yes. Every .NET Framework version higher than 4.0 is an in-place upgrade of 4.0.  Each higher version completely replaces the version before it on the machine.

You can still *target* .NET Framework 4.0 with a class library, but all that does is specify that you are using the *API* of .NET Framework 4.0. However, if you are running a more recent .NET Framework *runtime*, it will run the more recent version of .NET Framework. Basically, it goes into a compatibility mode that preserves the .NET Framework 4.0 behavior, but it is actually running on the newer .NET Framework version.

As for whether to *target* .NET Framework 4.0, that is a different issue. While it is true that Microsoft no longer supports .NET Framework 4.0, there is absolutely no reason why you cannot target .NET Framework 4.0 as long as the application that uses it is using a .NET Framework version that is still supported. The primary difference is that users who are stuck on the old version for whatever reason will still be able to use your class library, where if you target a more recent version, those stuck on .NET Framework 4.0 (and there are [plenty of possible reasons why this could occur](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/runtime/4.0-4.5)) won't be able to your library.

That being said, it is not recommended to run an application that targets an unsupported .NET Framework version. For a list of the .NET Framework versions that are still supported, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/dotnet-framework. This may seem to contradict what I just said, but there is a difference between *targeting* .NET Framework 4.0 vs *running* .NET Framework 4.0.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you clarify a little bit more the second paragraph, because the end is not so clear for me?
I'm developing a .NetFw4.8 dll whitch is used in .NetFw 4.0 app. Referencing dll in Visual Studio is not permited, but loading it by reflection doesn't cause problems.
The rest is clear for me. Thanks!

Comment: I have added in my question the complete example to clarify my example whitch is working well with no problems.

Comment: It is not possible to reference a *newer* version of .NET Framework using an older version. As you have discovered, it is possible to do it with Reflection, but that is far from ideal. Instead, I would recommend upgrading your console app to .NET Framework 4.8 also (even though that might involve changing more than the target framework).